# Develop a RSS feed list on Windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rss

We need to build a small Windows Forms app which displays latest RSS feeds from a website. It must be to similar to visual studio's start page. But, it also must display images. This can be easily achievable in ASP.NET with Repeater controls. I tried out DataRepeater & ListView in windows forms. Could not achieve it.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control, in which put generated HTML page or use WPF instead of WinForms.

Comment: You mean to say, apply XLST over the XML and display in 'WebBrowser' control?

Comment: @keevas, Yep, or any other way to generate HTML from XML, no matter.

Comment: How to do? can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to build WCF service and use `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` namespace members for this rather than parse manually HTML/XML...

See more details on how-to build a Feed: [SyndicationFeed class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx)

Comment: After getting the RSS, How would one put it on the screen in a better way?